# Python 3.6.1 says undefined value/variable after I have clearly defined it

Tags: python-3.x, function

The first program was written step wise and worked as I expected it to. This was after defining it wholly at once and it threw an error I described in the title. After running the second one, I did run the first one and the error was as I describe. I strongly feel in bones that I'm right especially after the first one worked the first time. Here's the first

```
a = {"piz":12, "san":23, "dg":45}

def see(a):
    if "dg" in a:
        r = a["dg"]
    return r
print (r)

def see(r):
    return r + 1

print (see(r))
```

And here's the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/util/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfileexecfile(filename, namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "/home/josh/python/viper.py", line 7, in <module>
print (r)
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

The second function is even "crazier", it creates one variable "e" and does not create another,  "f".

```
d = 3
a = [1,2,3]

b = [4,5,6]

c = [7,8,9]

#The function just checks if "d" is in "a", then creates variables "e" and   "f"
def enclosing():
    def abc(a, d):
        if d in a:
            print ("yes")
            print (a[0])
    e = a[0]
    f = a[1]
    return

    print (e) 
    print (f)
```

And its error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "/home/josh/python/d.py", line 25, in <module>
print (e)

NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Comment: Where have you _clearly_ defined `r` (when calling `print (r)`)? At that point your `r` is inside of a function (`see()`, and it will remain there anyway as it's not declared as a global) so of course Python complains when it doesn't know what you want it to print.

Comment: Learn a bit about _variable scopes_, where they exist and where they do not. Also note that if you define a function, it does not run until you actually call it. Random hit from the internet: https://www.smallsurething.com/how-variable-scope-works-in-python/ (while I have not read it in detail, it seems useful).

Comment: Thanks, now I see it's all about SCOPE. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't defining those variables where you intend to, or you're leaving them undefined in that scope. First of all, in the first snippet you have defined the same function twice, which is never a good idea. In the first definition, r is only defined if the statement `if "dg" in a:` evaluates to True. Thus you get an error if this is False (I recommend setting a placeholder value for r before the if statement).

In the second code snippet, you define two variables within a function, but then try to access them outside the function. Those variables are only defined within the function scope (in most languages, including python, variables defined within a function are local to that function, and can't be accessed outside of it) so you have to either set them as the return value of the function or make them global variables.

Comment: I intended the to design of the "IF" statement the way it was. Thanks, I see the rest is about scope now.

Comment: No problem. If you wouldn't mind upvoting and/or accepting I'd greatly appreciate it